# What happens in the code when emails and websites display the � character?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

I know that when emails and websites display �, something went wrong with character encoding along the way, but my understanding of exactly how encoding works is very limited - pretty much limited to knowing that (1) it makes no sense to have a string without an encoding - no such thing as "plain text," and (2) trying to merge two strings with different encodings leads to a corrupt result.  But I don't really understand exactly where in the process the interpretation of the foreign character is off.

Essentially what I'm looking for is a breakdown of the process of how a foreign character that is entered into an email by a user OR a foreign character that is entered into a string in the code by the programmer ultimately gets displayed incorrectly as �.  What is the original encoding?  What is the outputted encoding?  What happens along the way?  And how should this be fixed?

Comment: I'm struggling to make this question more specific because I'm looking for a basic understanding of the concept - I feel like in order to make this question more specific I would almost already need to know enough that would answer what I'm asking.  Is there a different stackexchange website that would be more equipped to handle this question in its current form?

Comment: Shame for above persons had closing this useful question. I agree with you, about this matter. Its now I'm researching in this issue similar Persian language and had ask some related question (No answered!) about, in stack overflow.